# GIt Workflow dev and production - where should I create the repos?

Tags: git-workflow

I've read somewhere* a setup like this would be nice:

**Two main branches, one for each server.**

Pushing to master sends changes on to live;

Pushing to dev/stage (or whatever you call it) sends changes to staging;

**Workflow:**

- Create branch from dev;
- work locally until you're ready to test;
- merge back to dev;
- push to Hub, which sends changes to dev/staging server.

*Once you're ready with those to go live:*

- merge from dev to master,
- then push master to Hub, which sends those changes on to the live server.

> **Two main branches, one for each server.**

So I have one branch "production" on "webroot/myliveapp/"
and another branch "development" on "webroot/devapp/"

**Where should the repository be ?**

**UPDATE:**

I mean:

We will have, according to this flow:

- Prime repo;
- Bare repo hub;
- Clones;

The development and production branches should belong to one repository, right ?

If this is correct, then were should we issue the FIRST git init command ?
On our Prime repo ?

So we will have:

> "webroot/myliveapp/" - production branch;
>
> "webroot/devapp/" - development branch;
>
> "webroot/.git" - Prime repository;

**Does this make sense ?**

Or should the Prime repository correspond to our production branch location ?

*Note: if you need a context about what workflow I'm trying to implement, is this one:
http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/

Comment: I understand the Git part, but I don't understand your question - Where should the repository be? Technically, every Git clone is a full copy of the repository, so _every machine_ that has a clone of your repository is where the repository is.

Comment: @Matt I've updated my question. Can you please take a look, and tell me if, what I'm writing does make sense to you ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the update on your question, it is more clear now.

I believe the problem you're having is based on a misunderstanding of Git workflow; Git doesn't equate **directories** to branches, it equates a **view of your filesystem** to branches. This is powerful - but easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Let me explain.

Git acts more like a database-backed, differentially-versioned, history tracking filesystem in itself. It is "above" your filesystem, not "part of" it. It doesn't use your filesystem to represent branches, rather, when you check out a different branch, *all the files in your filesystem will change to be the files in that branch*. You are asking Git to make your filesystem represent the alternate reality of that branch.

If you are on branch `master`, and it has a file `root/foo.txt` committed, and you check out branch `experiment`, which does *not* have `root/foo.txt` committed, you will find that file **gone** when you look for it. It is a part of `master`, not `experiment`, and so it is not present in your filesystem. This is why Git is really picky about your current branch being committed before it lets you switch branches - if you have unstaged changes on your filesystem that Git doesn't know about, it refuses to blow them away by overwriting them with a different reality. You have to intervene to make things right first.

So, to answer the quesiton, don't create subdirectories for "myliveapp" and "devapp" - create different *branches*.  Just have your one codebase under "webroot". Then, hack away on, say, the "unstable" branch, committing your changes as usual. You can then switch all of the files in your repository to be at the version of your dev server's files by switching to the "devapp" branch, and you can similarly switch back to "unstable" at any time.

When you want to update a branch, e.g. doing an update of your dev server, you can `merge` "unstable" into "devapp". This will make all of the files of "devapp" look like those of "unstable", bringing it up to date.

One other thing to note: the difference between a prime repo, a bare repo, and clones is almost nil. There is virtually no difference in the software; rather, it's a human convention to say "Linus' kernel is the canonical Linux kernel". With that understanding:

- A prime repo is just one repository that everyone agrees holds the "canonical" version of the software. That is, whenever a developer has made a change they want everyone to see, rather than saying, "Pull my version of devapp", they can say, "I've published my changes to our prime repo." It's simply an easy convention for people to rally around.
- A clone is a copy of some other repo. I could clone the prime repo, make changes, and then you can clone my repo. If you make changes, you can push them either onto the prime repo or onto mine, as long as the merge is valid and you have permissions on the computer.
- A bare repo simply has no "working copy" - there is no "webroot" directory on that computer. It's empty with *only* the `.git` directory - which is fine for servers where nobody needs to alter the files.

Finally, the `.git` dir doesn't hold the files of your repo, it holds the git configuration and database. It's your entire repository history in database form, which is used to populate the rest of the repo with a particular version of your software. That's why I made the comment: you can *locally* check out *any version of any alternate reality* of the repository, with no network communication, at any time - because it's all there in the .git dir. The only network communication necessary is for when you want to *sync* your local repository to some other repository, using `push` or `pull`.

Comment: at a first reading, you seem to have pointed exactly where my understanding problem was. By taking into consideration that branches are NOT directory related it's absolutely crucial that I re-read some of the documentation I have been reading. Please give me some time to diggest all, and get back after that. In a meanwhile, I will vote up, to thank your effort.

Comment: Can you please tell me if this conforms with what you are telling? http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/#comment-259589452 - I mean, here we do indeed have two directories, and, according to the branch we are in, we either pull from one or from another (I don't understand why push doesn't exist). Thanks again and again.

Comment: Oh, interesting. My take on this is that what he's doing is using two directories because he's got one machine running a webserver looking to the different directories _as different virtual hosts_. He's "deploying" locally by checking out the different branches in different dirs because that's the virtual host configuration, not how he's managing it in git. So one repo without two dirs, two branches, and his script is deploying each branch to a different hostname.

Comment: "So one repo without two dirs, two branches, and his script is deploying each branch to a different hostname." - and according to your guess, were should that prime repo be ? On neither of those directories, on one of them ? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: It looks like he's got it at `~/www/`, but it really doesn't matter. That is, he makes `~/www/` and runs `git init` in it. Then imagine he puts a `index.html` file in it and checks it into master. This will be his root html page. Then he creates a dev branch, changes the file, and checks it in. Now his script in that comment will deploy the repo - so he will have the master version in `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/index.html` and the dev version in `/var/www/vhosts/dev.domain.com/httpdocs/index.html`, and his web server is configured to serve a different site from each of those dirs.

Comment: So he's got his working repo in just any old directory, and under that directory is any file he wants to be available for his webserver - index.html, .htaccess, robots.txt, subdirectories, whatever. Then he deploys the two alternate realities to different directories. The only reason that two directories are necessary is because the webserver doesn't know about git branches - so the webserver thinks it's serving two totally different sites, but he's populating those sites with the files from the one repo, but different branches.

Comment: I now believe that I have all the information to try to deploy it. Thanks a lot for your patience on helping me out here. Cheers!